# Convert HTML from DB

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

I'm using TextAngular to save some posts to the database(with data type being `text`). It stores in the database like: `<h1>This is a header</h1>`. But when I go to retrieve from the database and display it in the HTML, it displays like `<h1>This is a header</h1>`.

Any idea how I can convert it either in the PHP or Javascript so it appears with the corresponding styles?

P.S.: I'm using Laravel for back-end(retrieval of data) and AngularJS for front-end(displaying data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to convert anything.
Just use `ng-bind-html`.

Take a look to the documentation for more information : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml